# Reading from different remote sources: how to optimize threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, remote-access

I need to read a huge number of web pages around the net. It's the method i'm actually using to get the remote webpage. Please note that the current code is 100% working.

```
    static private GetWebPageResult getWebPage(PageNode pagenode)
{
    String result;
    String inputLine;
    URI url;
    int cicliLettura=0;
    long startTime=0, endTime, openConnTime=0,connTime=0, readTime=0;
    try
    {
        startTime=System.nanoTime();
        result="";
        url=pagenode.getUri();      //fare qualcosa se getURI è null
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            openConnTime=System.nanoTime();
        if(url!=null)
        {
            HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.toURL().openConnection(); //controllare yc
            if(url.toURL().getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
                yc=(HttpsURLConnection)yc;
            yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"); 
            yc.connect();           //controllare il risultato di .connect => non c'è! al max lancia IOEXC
            if(checkResponseCode(yc.getResponseCode())==false)
                return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_BAD_RESPONSE_CODE,yc.getResponseCode());
            if(Core.logGetWebPage())
                connTime=System.nanoTime();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));//può lanciare IOEXC
            /*
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result=result+inputLine+"\n";
                cicliLettura++;
            }*/
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(inputLine).append('\n');
                cicliLettura++;
            }
            result = buffer.toString();

            if(Core.logGetWebPage())
                readTime=System.nanoTime();
            in.close();
            yc.disconnect();
            if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            {
                endTime=System.nanoTime();
                        //url.toURL() non è null, controllato prima
                System.out.println(/*result+*/"getWebPage eseguito in "+(endTime-startTime)/1000000+" ms. Size: "+result.length()+" Response Code="+yc.getResponseCode()+" Protocollo="+url.toURL().getProtocol()+" openConnTime: "+(openConnTime-startTime)/1000000+" connTime:"+(connTime-openConnTime)/1000000+" readTime:"+(readTime-connTime)/1000000+" cicliLettura="+cicliLettura+" pagina:"+url.toURL());
            }
            return new GetWebPageResult(result);
        }
        else
            return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_NULL_URI,-2);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione1: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_HTML_IOEXCEPTION,-2);
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione2: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_CLASS_CAST_EXC,-2);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione ERR_NOT_LISTED_EXC: "+e.toString());
        return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_NOT_LISTED_EXC,-2);
    }
}
```

Given that url is not null, let's look closely to the code

```
HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.toURL().openConnection(); //controllare yc
            if(url.toURL().getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
                yc=(HttpsURLConnection)yc;
            yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"); 
            yc.connect();           //controllare il risultato di .connect => non c'è! al max lancia IOEXC
            if(checkResponseCode(yc.getResponseCode())==false)
                return new GetWebPageResult(GetWebPageResult.ERR_BAD_RESPONSE_CODE,yc.getResponseCode());
```

What is the difference between .openConnection and .connect methods?
Anyway, when we have opened a connection, we start reading data

```
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));//può lanciare IOEXC
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(inputLine).append('\n');
                cicliLettura++;
            }
            result = buffer.toString();
```

Well, now i have a BufferedReader from which i read the data. The problem is that very often my bandwidth is far more large than the remote machine's bandwidth, so i want to be able to read from different sources at the "same time". A nice way seems to launch many threads, and modify the last part of code like this

While not end of file, then is there a full line to read? If yes, ask for a new line, else sleep a bit. At this point, i go on the next reading thread and make the same thing. Is it correct? How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic Producer/Consumer scenario. You can optimize your application by creating the following classes. If you are not already aware of the concept of a BlockingQueue and the producer-consumer problem, I recommend that you read [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html?m=1) before proceeding with my answer/design.

1. WebPageResult : A Pojo that represents the contents of a web page. Contains a StringBuffer to hold the results of a web page and the name/url of the Web page to identify what page the content is for.
2. ProcessingQueue : A singleton class that has [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) that holds PageNode objects and methods to add and poll a PageNode from this queue
3. ResultQueue : A singleton class that has [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) that holds WebPageResult objects and methods to add and poll a WebPageResult from this queue.
4. WebPageReader : Implements Runnable, calls the poll method from ProcessingQueue in its run method in a while(true) loop and reads the contents for the PageNode polled from the queue. The contents read from the PageNode should be wrapped into a WebPageResult and put into the ResultQueue by calling the add method in ResultQueue.
5. WebPageProcessor : Implements Runnable, calls the poll method from ResultQueue in its run method in a while(true) loop and then does whatever you want with this content.

All you need to do now is to add PageNode objects into the ProcessingQueue, start the WebPageReader and WebPageProcessor threads and watch the magic happen. Let me know if you need any clarification. Depending on your requirement, you can choose to start only one WebPageReader thread and WebPageProcessor thread or many. The design supports both. Also, you can introduce one more thread for adding PageNode objects to the ProcessingQueue by crawling the Web or polling some kind of a database for the pages that you want to crawl.

Comment: Of course it's interesting: i've made something similar for another application in a more raw way. The point i'm not getting is: where exactly do i consume bandwidth, and how can i say "if i have some free bandwidth, launch another thread and so get another page? (given that i know my max-bandwidth)"

Comment: You said, "While not end of file, then is there a full line to read? If yes, ask for a new line, else sleep a bit. At this point, i go on the next reading thread and make the same thing. Is it correct? How to implement this?". I think I have done a pretty good job in answering how to "implement this"